# PHP Array or array of Array

Tags: php

I am little confuse how to make below type of Array or Array of Array or key value pair in php.

For one stream1-->Array of devices and for each devices one machine name

Here is the example:

```
"Stream1" ---> "device type1" -> machine name1
          ---> "device type2" -> machine name2


"Stream2" ---> "device type3" -> machine name3
          ---> "device type4" -> machine name4
```

So in this example there are two streams named as "stream1" and "stram2". Each has multiple devices for e.g. "Stream1"--->"device type1" -> machine name1. Similarly, "Stream1"--->"device type2" -> machine name2.

So what is the best way in PHP to create this map either as Array or key value pair or Array of Array.

Once this map is created, how to write into a file in the same way?

Comment: What have you tried? In Stackoverflow people will help based on a solution you have tried and which did not work. Please provide a snippet of what you have tried till now. Because best way in PHP can be comparable only if we know you tried something which has flaws.

Comment: Sorry have not write any code yet and little confuse like how to approach this type of problem

Comment: This will be built by nested loops. As was said, we need some code example. Or some sample input / output.

Comment: @newbie83 perfectly alright. We are not expecting any apology. Firstly, search with already existing solutions of how to handle array with PHP (or your language), then try something out, if you get stuck, come back and there are people who can look into your code and help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks guys, i come up with an example that i am thinking to write a code in PHP. Any one knows how to do that:

Comment: Thanks guys, i come up with an example that i am thinking to write a code in PHP. Any one knows how to do that:

    "Day1":[{
              "name1":["John Hunter,","Clare Kinnear,","Scott 
                              Kinnear,"]    
            }
            ]
  
    "Day2":[{
              "name2":["John Hunter1,","Clare Kinnear1,","Scott 
                              Kinnear1"]    
            }
            ]

Answer (score 0):

This array example for you.

```
$map = array();
$map['Stream1']['device_type_1'] = 'machine name 1';
$map['Stream1']['device_type_2'] = 'machine name 2';
$map['Stream2']['device_type_3'] = 'machine name 3';
$map['Stream2']['device_type_4'] = 'machine name 4';
```

or if you want to make device type 1 have multiple machine you can make device type 1 as array. this is for example:

```
$map = array();
    $map['Stream1']['device_type_1'] = array('machine name 1','machine name 5', 'machine name 6');
    $map['Stream1']['device_type_2'] = 'machine name 2';
    $map['Stream2']['device_type_3'] = 'machine name 3';
    $map['Stream2']['device_type_4'] = 'machine name 4';
```